# Scrollview button cycle scroll to certain position, and go back to that position i currently was at

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I want to click a button. The scroll view will scroll to a certain `y` position and when I click it again it will return to that position I currently was at in the scroll view. I can't figure it out.

```
int position1 = 0;

- (IBAction)scrollToPosition1:(id)sender {
    int scrollYsaved;

    position1++;
    switch (position1) {
        case 1:
            scrollYsaved = scrollAll.contentOffset.y;

            [scrollAll scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(10, 4190, scrollAll.frame.size.width, scrollAll.frame.size.height) animated:YES];

            break;
        case 2:
            [scrollAll scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(10, scrollYsaved, scrollAll.frame.size.width, scrollAll.frame.size.height) animated:YES];

            if (position1=2)
            {
                position1=0;
            }

            break;
    }
```

Comment: `scrollYsaved` is local to the method.

Comment: How would i code this?

Comment: You have to store `scrollYsaved` outside the method, like `position1`.